# Is there any way to set auto increment sequence field in nest js and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nest

I have to create a field in mongoose that will be an auto increment sequence like XAT22000001, in this sequence means XAT is the exam name and 22 is the year and  the rest will be the reg number.

Answer (score 0):

Split this field into two fields. like ID = 'XAT22' + 1;